# Ckeditor not uploading images (Image source URL is missing.)

Tags: django, ckeditor

While creating blog posts I am unable to upload images through the editor. When I choose an image from my laptop and click 'OK' it says `Image source URL is missing.`

I'm using this package: https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import BlogPost
from ckeditor_uploader.widgets import CKEditorUploadingWidget

class BlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget())
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('__all__')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from autoslug import AutoSlugField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
import re
html_tags_re = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')


class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    featured_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/%Y/%m/%d')
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(null=True, default=None,
                         unique=True, populate_from='title')
                         
    @property
    def plain_text(self):
       return html_tags_re.sub('', self.content)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Posts"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
def create_blog_post_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BlogPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid:
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            redirect('news:blog_view')
    else:
        form = BlogPostForm

    context = {
        "form": form,
        "blog": BlogPost.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name="news/create_blog_post.html", context=context)
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
}

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
```

Edit: added views.py to my question

Comment: did you defined media path? I mean **MEDIA_URL** and **MEDIA_ROOT** ?

Comment: @DevangHingu I have `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`

Comment: And added `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` with  `urlpatterns` ? 
thanks

Comment: @DevangHingu That's correct

Comment: it would be a great if you can share you view

Comment: @DevangHingu I've updated my question